# Can I get a windows product key from my laptop which used to have windows xp/7?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, bios, product-key, product-key-recovery

I have a laptop which used to have windows 7 (and xp when it was originally purchased). However, I formatted the disk and now have Ubuntu 14.04 on it. I heard that the product key is embedded somewhere in the bios, so is there still hope to retrieve it?

Thanks

Comment: It's not for the version of Windows you used; if you don't have the Windows 7 key written down your out of luck

Comment: Assuming the right SLP key is really in your bios, you can read [here](https://superuser.com/questions/539714/windows-all-oem-activation), [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20100101022936/http://forums.mydigitallife.info/showthread.php?t=2602) and [here](https://forums.mydigitallife.info/threads/9795-The-Windows-XP-OEMBIOS-Archive). But tbh it would just be easier if you could just use the key you should find on the sticker glued on the bottom of your laptop.

Comment: Windows 7 and Windows XP used COA stickers

Comment: @mirh The sticker on the back is for XP, so that wont work.

Comment: What are you talking about then? If the PC shipped with XP, that's what -if any- it will "contain".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If, as you've stated, the product key you're trying to recover:

- Isn't on the COA label affixed to your computer
- Isn't accessible on-disk due to your having formatted the disk
- Isn't written down anywhere

Then, **you've lost the product key**.

> I heard that the product key is embedded somewhere in the bios

What you're referring to is known as [Digital Entitlement](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12440/windows-10-activation). This activation method is not available for Windows 7.

Comment: The part of your answer about Digital Entitlement is wrong. Digital Entitlement replaces the product key altogether and has nothing to do with the BIOS-embedded product keys. Those product keys were introduced with Windows 8. Of course, the OP does not have BIOS-embedded product key, because of his ancient hardware.

Comment: @FleetCommand Yeah, I realized that after posting but couldn't find the marketing "name" for the embedded key types. Do you know what it is?

Comment: They don't have a name for it. (The didn't even put a name on their famous design language which we have come to known as Metro! So, one must not be surprised that they didn't name something so mundane.)